# 日本人は日本語で番号を書くなら、アメリカの小数点かヨーロッパのを書きますの？

Tags: orthography, numbers, symbols

皆さん、こんにちは！

日本人は日本語に番号を書くことを学びますなら、

アメリカ風の小数点(1.0)か、ヨーロッパ風の(1,0)を書くことを学びますか？

日本語だけで尋ねてみたいですよ。

でも私の日本語もよくないんで、すみません。:)

ありがとう！:D

エディット:今、日本語だけで、英語じゃないです。

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off-topic.

Comment: ah, it was about when learning English

Comment: If this is going to be closed as off-topic, I might as well tell that in Finland you're supposed to write "1,0" but because of American influence many of us write "1.0" and even talk about dots instead of commas (yksi **piste** nolla). Btw, I think that even Brits use "1.0" _unlike_ Europeans :)

Comment: I rephrased the question (よくない日本語で・・・) so now it's supposed to be asking about what they use in Japanese, aka. their own language.

Comment: 小数点のことですよね？それとも桁区切りの方？

Comment: @broccoliforest 『アメリカ風の「1.0」』だから小数点のことだと思います

Comment: 関係ないのですが、「～するの？」を丁寧語にする時はふつう「～するのですか？」とします。「～しますの？」は[この人](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E7%99%BD%E4%BA%95%E9%BB%92%E5%AD%90)の話し方です。

Comment: @broccoliforest そうだったかな。はっきり覚えているのは「お姉さま〜」だけですｗ

Comment: @broccoliforest あ！「 ジャッジメントですの」とかよくいいましたよね。放映された時は日本語が大体分からなかったから即座に覚えてなかった

Answer (score 3, accepted):

日本語学習者です！

英語版ウィキペディアの記事「[Decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)」によれば、日本において正しい書き方はアメリカと同じく「1.0」です。

記事にある地図には他の国の書き方も含めています。見てのとおり、イギリスも水色なので他の書き方（1,0）は「イギリス風」ではなく、ヨーロッパ風です。

[image]

Comment: ありがとう！どうしてカナダもその色なの？

Comment: @Tirous カナダの書き方は言語に依存します。フランス語なら「1,0」と英語で他の水色の国のように「1.0」です。カナダの色は緑と水色の混じりだと思います。

Comment: @Tirous この回答はbroccoli forestさんの回答よりわかりやすいならいいけど質問の「日本語の番号の小数点」なら彼の回答のほうがずっといいと思います！

Answer (score 2):

日本語でのアラビア数字の区切りは英語式で、小数点には**ピリオド**、桁区切りには**コンマ**を使います。つまり「十二万三千四百五十六[・]{てん}七八」は、

> 123,456.78

です。

---

ちなみに、漢数字で書く時は小数点に**中黒**を使います。

> 一二三四五六・七八

また、桁区切りには**読点**を使います。3桁ずつ区切る人も4桁ずつの人もいます。

> 一二三、四五六・七八
>   一二、三四五六・七八

（ごくまれに、アラビア数字でも4桁で区切る人 [12,3456.78] もいますが、忘れて構いません）